# The new quote function in my script.js file does not make the author name appear

Tags: javascript

Every time I click the new code button the author's name is 'Unknown' And note the one provided by the API provided data.
The code is in this Codepen:

https://codepen.io/osvaldogrc/pen/poPLyzW

```
const quoteContainer = document.getElementById('quote-container');
const quoteText = document.getElementById('quote');
const authorText = document.getElementById('author');
const twitterBtn= document.getElementById('twitter');
const newQuoteBtn = document.getElementById('new-quote');
const loader = document.getElementById('loader');

let apiQuotes = [];
//New Quote
function newQuote(){
    complete();
    //Random quote
    const quote = apiQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * apiQuotes.length)];
    
    quoteText.textContent = quote.text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the `author` property of the response object to the `textContent` of the corresponding `span`:

```js
const quoteContainer = document.getElementById('quote-container');
const quoteText = document.getElementById('quote');
const authorText = document.getElementById('author');
const twitterBtn= document.getElementById('twitter');
const newQuoteBtn = document.getElementById('new-quote');
const loader = document.getElementById('loader');


let apiQuotes = [];

// Show loading
function loading() {
    loader.hidden = false;
    quoteContainer.hidden = true;

}

// Hide loading
function complete() {
    quoteContainer.hidden = false;
    loader.hidden =true;
}
//New Quote
function newQuote(){
    complete();
    //Random quote
    const quote = apiQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * apiQuotes.length)];
    
    quoteText.textContent = quote.text;
  author.textContent = quote.author;
}

// Check quote length
if(quoteText.length > 50) {
    quoteText.classList.add('long-quote');
} else {
    quoteText.classList.remove('long-quote');
}
// Set quote
quoteText.textContent = quoteText;
complete();
//Author field
authorText.textContent = quote.author ? quote.author : "Unknown";
//Get Quotes fom API
async function getQuotes(){
    loading();
    const apiUrl = `https://type.fit/api/quotes`;
    try {
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
        apiQuotes = await response.json();
        newQuote();
    } catch (error){
        //Error here
    }
}
//Twee
function tweetQuote() {
    const twitterUrl =`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${quoteText.textContent} - ${authorText.textContent}`;
    window.open(twitterUrl, '_blank');
}

//Event Listener 
newQuoteBtn.addEventListener('click', newQuote);
twitterBtn.addEventListener('click', tweetQuote)
//On load
getQuotes();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #DFDBE5;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='48' height='32' viewBox='0 0 48 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg fill='none' fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg fill='%239C92AC' fill-opacity='0.4'%3E%3Cpath d='M27 32c0-3.314 2.686-6 6-6 5.523 0 10-4.477 10-10S38.523 6 33 6c-3.314 0-6-2.686-6-6h2c0 2.21 1.79 4 4 4 6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12s-5.373 12-12 12c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4h-2zm-6 0c0-3.314-2.686-6-6-6-5.523 0-10-4.477-10-10S9.477 6 15 6c3.314 0 6-2.686 6-6h-2c0 2.21-1.79 4-4 4C8.373 4 3 9.373 3 16s5.373 12 12 12c2.21 0 4 1.79 4 4h2z' /%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
color: black;
font-family: Montserrar, sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
} 
.quote-container{
    width: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.quote-text {
    font-size: 2.75rem; 
}

#long-quote{
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.fa-quote-left{
    font-size: 4rem;
}
.quote-author{
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
}
.button-container {
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
button{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.8rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0.3rem rgba(121, 121, 121, 0.65);
}
button:hover{
    filter: brightness(110%);
}

button:active{
    transform: translate(0, 0.3rem);
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
}
.twitter-button:hover{
    color: #38a1f3;
}
.fa-twitter{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

/* Media query*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .quote-container{
        margin: auto 10px;
    }
    .quote-text{
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
}
/*Loader*/
.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid#333; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quote Generator</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://www.google.com/s2/u/0/favicons?domain=css-tricks.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="quote-container" id="quote-container">
        <div class="quote-text">
            <!--Quote-->
            <i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i>
            <span id="quote"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- Author-->
        <div class="quote-author">
            <span id="author"></span>
        </div>
        <!--Buttons-->
        <div class="button-container">
            <button class="twitter-button" id="twitter" title="Tweet This!">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            </button>
            <button id="new-quote">New Quote</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Loader-->
    <div class="loader" id="loader"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="quotes.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`newQuote` only set `quoteText.textContent

try adding `authorText.textContent = quote.author ? quote.author : "Unknown";` in the function

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in the `newQuote` function are you setting a value to the "author text".  If you want to set a value to `authorText`, set a value to `authorText`:

```
authorText.textContent = quote.author;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding authorText.textContent in line 30 of the code resolved the issue.

Thanks to everyone.

```
//New Quote
function newQuote(){
    complete();
    //Random quote
    const quote = apiQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * apiQuotes.length)];

    quoteText.textContent = quote.text;
    authorText.textContent = quote.author;
}
```